# NPE while getting auto incremented key in Oracle 12C jdbc driver

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

I am getting NPE while getting back the auto incremented key in oracle 12c. I am using ojdbc7.jar downloaded from oracle site for oracle 12c. Version - 12.1.0.1.0. Here is the stack trace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.jdbc.driver.AutoKeyInfo.initMetaDataKeyFlag(AutoKeyInfo.java:404)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.AutoKeyInfo.initMetaData(AutoKeyInfo.java:392)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleReturnResultSet.getMetaData(OracleReturnResultSet.java:77)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getMetaData(DelegatingResultSet.java:322)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getMetaData(DelegatingResultSet.java:322)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ColumnMapRowMapper.mapRow(ColumnMapRowMapper.java:52)
```

I am using spring jdbc and its keyHolder to get the key back.While in oracle side using sequence to generate the id.

Read somewhere in hibernate forum, its a bug in jdbc driver itself but the oracle forum is restricted for me.
[Hibernate forum link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8519).
Anyone having same problem and how they are tackling this issue.

Sample code :

```
public Double insert(Definition definition) {
    final String name = definition.getName();
    final String desc = definition.getDesc();
    final String type= definition.getType();
    final String insertSql = "INSERT INTO DEFINITION (ID, TYPE, NAME, DESC) VALUES (MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?)";
    KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

    getJdbcTemplate().update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {           

                    @Override
                    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection)
                            throws SQLException {
                        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(insertSql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                        ps.setString(1, type);
                        ps.setString(2, name);
                        ps.setString(3, desc);
                        return ps;
                    }
                }, holder);

    Double generatedId = holder.getKey().doubleValue();
    return generatedId;
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: which JDBC driver **version** are you using? You can get that using `DatabaseMetaData.getDriverVersion()` (the number in the jar file's name is **not** the driver version)

Comment: Update the question by adding the sample code and driver info.

Comment: "ojdbc7.jar" is not a version, it means it is for Java 7. Which version of the driver are you using?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure here but maybe you should use `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... RETURING`. The `RETURNING` clause is intended for this purpose. Also do not convert Oracle NUMBER into Double. You should use BigDecimal for identifiers.

Comment: PS: with newer drivers you can get the version by simply "executing" the driver. Run "java -jar ojdbc7.jar" and it will print the version.

Comment: Can you also describe the table "DEFINITION"? What are the column data types?

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8519

Answer (score 2):

It has been fixed in driver version 12.2. When that is public you will have a fix, else you may contact oracle support and ask for a driver patch.

Still waiting for the public release of 12.2

Comment: I will wait for that in the meantime I have already moved to hibernate.

Comment: I am using 12.2.0, but still getting the same error. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: In my case changing to ojdbc8 12.2.0.1 helped and no NPE occured after upgrading. After U upgrade try  ``PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(insertSql,new String[]{"YOUR_ID"});..``